# Bitnami LAMP Stack ec2 encryption

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp, bitnami

I am a newbie to AWS and Bitnami LAMP.  I loaded a Bitnami LAMP ec2 instance and I need to ready it for HIPAA.  My question more specifically is how do I encrypt the data on the stack?

Is it already encrypted?
Does the LAMP setup put the database on a separate EBS Volume that I can encrypt?
If so do I encrypt the EBS Volume?

I am using version 5.4.17-0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You need to define how and what you need encrypted. Do you need volume encryption? are you encrypting specific data stored in a database? is connectivity encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to attach an EBS Volume, encrypt it, mount it, and move my MySQL database to it.  The links that are most helpful are:

Encrypting a volume: http://www.cromwell-intl.com/security/ec2-secure-storage.html

Copy Database to volume:  http://dunniganp.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/moving-a-mysql-database-from-one-ebs-volume-to-another-on-aws-ec2/